# При установке Android приложения делать сразу ярлык на "рабочем столе"

Tags: java, android, ярлыки

Нужно чтобы при установке приложения, его ярлык добавлялся на главный экран, на любое (первое) свободное место.
Это возможно в принципе?

Answer (score 1):

Такая опция точно есть у GooglePlay. А вот при установке самого приложения наверно не получится - в apk нет иструментов для запуска кода во время инсталляции.

К тому же не забывайте, что вариантов "главных экранов" в андроиде может быть много, поэтому универсальной функции наверно не будет.

Comment: Так и имеется ввиду что на любой главный экран, на первое свободное место.

Comment: @Phantom а если я свой главный экран создам, без свободных мест?

Comment: хм, ну как возможное решение - если нет свободного места, то не ставить ярлык.
судя по всему такой возможности нет

Comment: @Phantom я не про то, если честно. Дело в том что контролировать главный экран вы вряд ли сможете (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_HOME)